# AngularJS 1.5: curly notation not working, but ng-bind is?

Tags: angularjs

Im relatively new to Angular, but I have the following HTMl:

```
{{myValue}}
```

backed by the following controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', '$state', '$window', '$log', '$sce', 'Authentication',
    function($scope, $state, $window, $log, $sce, Authentication) {
        $scope.myValue = 'testing';
```

Can someone tell me why only the latter `myValue` is working within the HTML?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show more of your HTML and where you register your app module? See [mcve] for more info.

Comment: What do you mean by "the latter" `myValue` is working within the HTML. What is displaying and what would you like to display?

Comment: Sorry Lex and Andy.  When I posted the question, I had the HTML tags, but I didn't escape them properly, so you're seeing the render of the HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  It was a conflict with the render template engine, swig.